# angular 2+ and kendo angular add computed class

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-angular-ui

I want to add css class to my `span` element `class="badge badge-danger"`

```
<kendo-grid-column field="inactive" title="Enabled" width="20%">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-subType>
        <span [class]="'badge badge-' + subType.inactive ? 'danger' : 'primary'">123</span>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

But in result I have `<span class="danger"`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use parenthesizes

`[class]="'badge badge-' + (subType.inactive ? 'danger' : 'primary')"`